# Grid server filtering

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I would like to disable client side filtering and enable server side filtering.
All in all I would like reuse grid filtering components but do nothing on clientside, sending to server a copy to CompositeFilterDescriptor and get data filtered.
Btw I would like to do this using pagination on grid.

How can I achieve this? Is not clear to me how to

1. showing filters but disable client filtering action
2. how to bind CompositeFilterDescriptor object on my component. May I copy it on every filterChange event or are there some smartest methods to bind it?

Comment: everytime you change the sort, filter, order, group, etc of the grid, you need to call the server so the server can return you what should be displayed

Comment: Sure, this is clear to me. The point is about questions 1 and 2

Comment: well for point 1, you intercept each action and send a call to the server with the current grid state and it should return you the appropriate data